# tr:hover override not triggering in Dash

Tags: css, plotly-dash

I am new to Dash but not new to python or html and css.

I have a relatively basic structure that renders a [DataTable](https://dash.plotly.com/datatable) which looks like:

```
def render_datatable(df=None, id=None):
    dt1= dash_table.DataTable(
        id=id,
        columns=[{"name": i, "id": i} for i in df.columns],
        data=df.to_dict('records'),
        style_data={'height':'auto'},
        fill_width=False,
    )

    return dt1
```

That `DataTable` is rendered into an `html.Div` element as:

```
    html.Div(className='col-sm',
             children=my_rendered_datatable
             )
```

Within my `Project/assets/css/custom.css` I have a simple override:

```
*{

    font-family: Poppins;

}


*:hover {background-color: yellow;}
```

My site and my datatable render without issue:
[image]

But, as you can see, when I have the `tr` row hovered (forced state within chrome inspection), I need to actually hover on the `<div>` vs the `<tr>`.

My question is how do I enable hover in a DataTable row within Dash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could change the background color of each row on hover like this

```
table.cell-table tr:hover td.dash-cell {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

The reason what you had before wasn't working was due to your style declarations lacking [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity).

> Specificity is the means by which browsers decide which CSS property values are the most relevant to an element and, therefore, will be applied...
>
> Specificity is a weight that is applied to a given CSS declaration, determined by the number of each selector type in the matching selector. When multiple declarations have equal specificity, the last declaration found in the CSS is applied to the element. Specificity only applies when the same element is targeted by multiple declarations. As per CSS rules, directly targeted elements will always take precedence over rules which an element inherits from its ancestor.